# Enviar codigo html a otra html y que lo interprete con html

Tags: python-3.x, django-3.2.4

podrian ayudarme por favor con lo siguiente:
Tengo una tabla que almacena codigo html, ademas tengo 2 archivos html, index y plantilla_portada.
El problema es que no estoy usando bien mi funcion archivobase que esta en views... no entiendo bien como puedo hacer para que el navegador, o django, o python interprente en codigo html.

Index: recibe codigo html y lo reenvia a plantilla_portada

plantilla_portada: es el que finalmente muestra al cliente todo lo que necesita ver.

Creo que tengo error en concepto, y ya se dieron cuenta que soy re nuevo en esto, desde ya gracias.

### Esto es lo que hay dentro del campo de mi tabla:

```
<font size=7 color="red">Hola mundo</font>
```

Y  cuando lo ejecuto, en mi pagina web en lugar de salir: Hola mundo en tamaño 7 y color rojo me Sale:

```
<font size=7 color="red">Hola mundo</font>
```

### mi tabla

```
class Plantillashtml(models.Model):
    ModelManager = models.Manager()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigohtml = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

### index:

```
{% extends 'base/plantilla_portada.html' %}


{% block titulo %}
    {% include 'base/plantilla_header.html' %}
{% endblock %}


{% block ENCABEZADOSITIOWEB %}
    <h1>Encabezado</h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block contenidogeneral %}
    {{ v_html}}
{% endblock %}

{% block piedelsitioweb %}  {% endblock %}
```

### plantilla_portada:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block titulo %} <h1>PLANTILLA.............PORTADA HEADER </h1> {% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block ENCABEZADOSITIOWEB %} <H1>PLANTILLA.............PORTADA ENCABEZADO DE LA PORTADA</H1> {% endblock %}



        {% block contenidogeneral %} <h1>PLANTILLA.............PORTADA CONTENIDOaaaa </h1> {% endblock %}



        {% block piedelsitioweb %} <h1>PLANTILLA.............PORTADA pie del archivo base</h1> {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Plantillashtml
# Create your views here.

def archivobase(request):
    traerhtml = Plantillashtml.ModelManager.all().filter(id=1)  # si no colocamos esta linea, por defecto es como si estuviera objects = models.Manager()
    t = loader.get_template('base/index.html')
    for c in traerhtml:
        varr = {"v_html": c.codigohtml}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(varr, request), content_type='application/html')
```